# Engine problems ( I think its the man working on my car)

Tags: engine, chevrolet, camaro

I have a 1997 Camaro 5 speed (3.8L V6 engine). I bought this car and hauled it home on a tow dolly. I never tried too start it and the car has been sitting for a good 3 or 4 years now. Battery is totally dead. I jumped it, it starts and dies. I think there's fuel in it, but I do have a really bad person working on it ... it's called my ex. Anyway, why would it keep dying and has no power? Would it be the EGR valve? And should I replace a lot of things cause its been sitting a long time?

Comment: Are you sure it is a bad mechanic or did you just buy a dog...

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a new mechanic. If you can't trust the person working on your car, you need someone else that you *can* trust.
2. Is the fuel old? If so, your mechanic should start by flushing it all out and replacing with fresh fuel.
3. Put a new battery in, and try to start it. Then read the OBD codes to see what's giving the most important issues. Might it need a new EGR valve? Possibly, but we don't know. You need to diagnose the issues in order, and not just throwing parts at the car in the hope that they'll make it work.

Comment: While the mechanic may or may not be the primary issue, I'd agree with starting with the fuel. Putting fresh fuel and something like Seafoam or BG44-K in with the fresh fuel would go a long way. Sounds like old/bad fuel and gummed up injectors would be the best place to start. Then, don't be surprised if the fuel pump gives up the ghost in the near future.